# How to pass columns to rows in the new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new dataframe `new` based on `df`:

```
df = 
ID   GROUP_1   GROUP_2    GROUP_3   COUNT   NAME
1    AAA       AAA        CCC       5       xxx
2    BBB       CCC        AAA       6       yyy
```

The result should be this one:

```
new =
ID   GROUP  COUNT  NAME
1    AAA    5      xxx
1    CCC    5      xxx
2    BBB    6      yyy
2    CCC    6      yyy
2    AAA    6      yyy
```

So, I want to pass into row the values of `GROUP_1`, `GROUP_2` and `GROUP_3` (in reality I have much more columns starting with `GROUP_`, that's why I'd prefer to use `df.filter(regex = "^GROUP")`).

How can I do this considering that the dataset is quite big (around 1Gb)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***method 1***
use `pd.melt`

```
cols = ['ID', 'GROUP', 'COUNT', 'NAME']
pd.melt(
    df, ['ID', 'COUNT', 'NAME'],
    ['GROUP_1', 'GROUP_2', 'GROUP_3'],
    value_name='GROUP')[cols]
```

***method 2***
`set_index` + `stack`

```
cols = ['ID', 'GROUP', 'COUNT', 'NAME']
df.set_index(['ID', 'COUNT', 'NAME']).stack().reset_index(name='GROUP')[cols]
```

---

```
   ID GROUP  COUNT NAME
0   1   AAA      5  xxx
1   1   AAA      5  xxx
2   1   CCC      5  xxx
3   2   BBB      6  yyy
4   2   CCC      6  yyy
5   2   AAA      6  yyy
```

Comment: Fantastic. I knew there'd be a way to avoid awkward for-loops and manual faffing.

Comment: The second method is probably more flexible. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate if you could take a look at my next related question (I am using your solution there): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471794/how-to-pass-to-rows-multiple-groups-of-columns