# How to pass to rows multiple groups of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the continuation of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471350/how-to-pass-columns-to-rows-in-the-new-dataframe).

I have the data set:

```
df = 
ID   GROUP_1   GROUP_2    GROUP_3   COUNT   NAME_1   NAME_2
1    AAA       AAA        CCC       5       xxx      yyy
2    BBB       CCC        AAA       6       yyy      zzz
```

The result should be this one:

```
new =
ID   GROUP  COUNT  NAME
1    AAA    5      xxx
1    AAA    5      yyy
1    CCC    5      xxx
1    CCC    5      yyy
2    BBB    6      yyy
2    BBB    6      zzz
2    CCC    6      yyy
2    CCC    6      zzz
2    AAA    6      yyy
2    AAA    6      zzz
```

I want to pass into row the values of GROUP_1, GROUP_2 and GROUP_3, AND `NAME_1` and `NAME_2` (considering that the number of columns starting with `GROUP` and `NAME` is big, so I don't want to manually enumerate them).

I am currently using the solution proposed in my previous question mentioned above:

```
cols = ['ID', 'GROUP', 'COUNT', 'NAME']
df.set_index(['ID', 'COUNT', 'NAME']).stack().reset_index(name='GROUP')[cols]
```

However, the problem is that I should apply the same procedure to `NAME`. Is it possible to update this solution considering that there are multiple groups of columns that should be passed to rows?

Comment: Please show what desired output is.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy: Please see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `melt` twice using the same method as the previous answer

First melt the NAME columns into one column

```
df1 = pd.melt(
    df, ['ID', 'COUNT', 'GROUP_1', 'GROUP_2', 'GROUP_3'],
    ['NAME_1', 'NAME_2'],
    value_name='NAME').drop('variable', axis=1)
```

Output

```
   ID  COUNT GROUP_1 GROUP_2 GROUP_3 NAME
0   1      5     AAA     AAA     CCC  xxx
1   2      6     BBB     CCC     AAA  yyy
2   1      5     AAA     AAA     CCC  yyy
3   2      6     BBB     CCC     AAA  zzz
```

Then melt this one again by the GROUP columns

```
df2 = pd.melt(
    df1, ['ID', 'COUNT', 'NAME'],
    ['GROUP_1', 'GROUP_2', 'GROUP_3'],
    value_name='GROUP').drop('variable', axis=1).drop_duplicates()
```

Output

```
    ID  COUNT NAME GROUP
0    1      5  xxx   AAA
1    2      6  yyy   BBB
2    1      5  yyy   AAA
3    2      6  zzz   BBB
5    2      6  yyy   CCC
7    2      6  zzz   CCC
8    1      5  xxx   CCC
9    2      6  yyy   AAA
10   1      5  yyy   CCC
11   2      6  zzz   AAA
```